# xml to xml transformation without xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to transform one xml to another without the other one having an xslt.

Both the xmls are related, but have different structures.

Whatever i have explored till now suggests that there is a need for xslt for doing the transformation.

Please suggest.

Regards

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use XSLT - the tool created specifically for this task?

Comment: The only reason being that i dont have a xslt for the xml.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a xslt for the xml". An XSLT stylesheet needs to transform from one specific XML schema to another. IOW, it needs to be custom-written to accommodate both input and output.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the misconception. Can you suggest a xslt generator?

Comment: I use the one between my ears ;-). I believe both Altova MapForce and Stylus Studio offer some type of a visual tool for creating an XSLT stylesheet, but I have never used either one.

Answer (score 2):

There are many techologies you can use for transforming XML. XSLT is probably the most popular, for good reasons.

Whatever technology you choose, you will need to define the transformation. No tool in the world can work out for itself that the rule for transforming `<a>2</a>` to `<b>4</b>` is to modify element names by changing the first letter to whatever comes next in the alphabet, and to change the values by adding 2.

There are some tools (such as Altova Mapforce) for generating XSLT to do simple transformations. You may find them useful (but I don't).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

- Read the XML file into a DOM, using any of a variety of XML readers. ([Example](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp))
- The DOM offers an API for inspection and modification its contents; write code that uses this API to find the location of change and make changes
- Write the DOM contents back out as XML.

Comment: Thanks Ira. I guess i would then have to use the xerces dom parser for doing so.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i would be doing it via a c++ program. Hence the mention of the xerces dom parser. Is there any other library to do so, with a smaller memory foorprint?